# How to get 'instance' (class) from 'this' in ecma 6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I mean not name of class as string, I need the completely static instance.

```
class Secret {

   createNewClassFromConstructorName()
   {
       let className = this.constructor.name;

       return new className();
   }
}


let secret = new Secret();
```

But I don't want to create some attributes like 'this.self = Secret or this.instance = Secret' or methods which returns the instance. I want to access them from 'this' statement. And on run this method:

```
secret.createNewClassFromConstructorName();
```

I'v get the error, when the 'className' is not a constructor.

Comment: i need it because i have the dynamic classes instances.

Comment: Well, `.name` is a name string, not a class. Why did you access it? Just use `var clas = this.constructor`.

Comment: yup. its works. Thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the `constructor` property as the constructor!

```
createNewClassFromConstructorName() {
   return new this.constructor;
}
```